Understanding the various ML Export Format
Out of the various types of ML Export Formats - YAML, Pickle, ONNX, etc. - which one do you use and why? For example, is there any benefit to choosing Pickle over ONNX?
I have tried to find expert opinions of this online, but nothing pops up.

YAML and Pickle are not related to machine learning. YAML is a markup language, often used for configuration files. Pickle is a general purpose serialization format specific to Python.

Of the formats you listed, only ONNX is specific to representing neural networks.
